# A question on the existence of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $a, b, c$ be three real numbers such that $a+b+c=0$. Prove that there exists a polynomial $P$ such that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have 
$a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}=abc[P(a, b)+P(b, c)+P(c, a)]$

I can prove by induction that $abc\ |\ 2(a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1})$ but I can't show the existence of $P$ or what it might be.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Something is wrong here. RHS does not depend on $n$. Please double check the problem statement.

Comment: @user58697. Right. What  should be said is that for each $n$ there exists a polynomial $P_n$ such that....

Answer (score 1):

For $n=0$ let $P\equiv 0$ because the LHS is $0.$

For $n\geq 1$ let $F_n= a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}+c^{2n+1}.$  We have $$F_n=a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}-(a+b)^{2n+1}=-\sum_{j=1}^{2n}a^{2n+1-j}b^j\binom {2n+1}{j}=$$ $$=-ab\sum_{j=1}^{2n}a^{2n-j}b^{j-1}\binom {2n+1}{j}.$$  Let $G_n(a)=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}a^{2n-j}(-a)^{j-1}\binom {2n+1}{j}.$ Observe that $G_n(a)=0$ because, when  $a\ne 0$ we have $G_n(a)=a^{-2}([a+(-a)]^{2n+1}-[a^{2n+1}+(-a)^{2n+1}])=0,$ and when $a=0$ every term in the summation defining $G_n(a)$ is $0.$

Therefore  $$F_n=F_n+abG_n(a)=-ab\sum_{j=1}^{2n}a^{2n-j}(b^{j-1}-(-a)^{j-1})\binom {2n+1}{j}.$$ Now for any $j\geq 1$ we have $b^{j-1}-(-a)^{j-1}=(b+a)Q_j(a,b)=-cQ_j(a,b)$ where $Q_j$ is a polynomial.

So $F_n=-ab\sum_{j=1}^{2n}a^{2n-j}(-c)Q_j(a,b)\binom {2n+1}{j}=abcP_n(a,b)$ where $P_n(a,b)=\sum_{j=1}^{2n}a^{2n-j}Q_j(a,b)\binom {2n+1}{j}.$ Cyclically permuting the values $a,b,c $ and adding, we obtain $$3F_n=abc (P_n(a,b)+P_n(b,c)+P_n(c,a)).$$